# IBus Pinyin: What key to press to scroll to next Chinese character?

Tags: shortcut-keys, ibus, pinyin

I'm using the **IBus 1.5.11** input-method framework to type Japanese (**Anthy** input-method package) which works perfectly well. I can input Roman characters and press `Space` key to scroll through all word or kanji character suggestions and then press `Enter` key to pick my choice.

But if i use the **Pinyin** input-method package to type Chinese, the `Space` key seems to have another function. It does not switch through the other Hanzi character suggestions but instead has the `Enter` key effect. Which brings me to my 2 questions:

(1) what key do i have to press to switch through the different character suggestions?

(2) Why was Space key implemented in such weird way?

It seems that only clicking on the character suggestion via mouse works which is kind of stupid, it slows down my typing progress. It would be a pain if i have to switch to another input-method framework such as **Fcitx** because the **Anthy** package for Japanese, which i use on a regular basis on **IBus**, works perfectly. Hope i can get help for this issue!

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?

Comment: I haven't figured it out XD